# closed-form of an integral with regard to $a$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

Suppose that $a$ is a constant and $a>1$. So how can we evaluate the integral
$$
I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{t}{(a-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}}\;dt
$$
I just wonder if there is a closed-form. Thank you.

Comment: @Fabian, are you sure that is correct? I get something like $$\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}-1\Bigr)+\frac{a\text{arccot}\,\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a^2-1}},$$ which seems to differ from your result. I cannot swear I'm correct, though :)

Comment: @mickep: I evaluated a different integral ;-) (deleted my comment).

Comment: @mickep: a small comment: $\mathop{\rm arccot}(\sqrt{a^2-1}) = \arcsin(1/a)$

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding and subtracting $a$ in the numerator,
$$
\frac{t}{(a-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{t-a+a}{(a-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\frac{a}{(a-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}}.
$$
The first term gives an inverse sine, for the second term, let
$$
u=\frac{at-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
and you will get a simple primitive. Since you did not show any effort, I will stop here.

Answer (score 0):

It can be transformed in a trigonometric integral using the change $t = \sin z$:
$$\int\frac{t}{(a-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt = \int\frac{a\sin z}{a-\sin z}\,dz.$$
Now you can use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

The form of the solution depends of $|a|$ ($<1$, $=1$, $>1$).

Comment: Actually, isn't the numerator $\sin z$ after the substitution? :-)

Comment: @Brightsun, yes, corrected. Thanks.